# How to Export fonts, Layer Styles, and other settings of Photoshop CS6 from one machine to another

Tags: adobe-photoshop

Well, Let me put it this way, I had a PC on which I use to do all my designing work. It was like a home for me, I had all fonts installed, Layer styles saved, Swatches, and many more things. But recently I bought another PC and now I was wondering if there is a way to export every Photoshop stuff I had on my old PC to my New PC. Any help will be really appreciated.. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to manually save any custom brushes, swatches, styles, etc you may have created. Until you save these items manually by choosing "Save XXX" from the appropriate flyout menu on the appropriate panel, nothing is a physical file. When you do choose to save them, you can indicate where on your hard drive you'd like them to be placed.

Once you have all the physical files, you can then simply copy them to the new system and place them into Adobe Photoshop/Presets/en_us (or your language)/ and then to the correct folder - brushes in brushes, styles in styles, etc.

As for fonts, that's a different matter. Fonts are system files and to transfer those you need to move them from the old system folders to the new system folder.

Other than a complete system backup and restore, there's no automated method to move everything to a new system.

The **Creative Cloud version of Photoshop** released June 17, 2013 has a **"sync" option** in the **Preferences** which allows you to synchronize custom items using the Creative Cloud. However, you must be a Creative Cloud subscriber to use this feature.